# Can I play an online game from one account if a second account has PS Plus?

Tags: ps4, psn, call-of-duty-black-ops-3

I have black ops 3 as a free monthly game on an old account.

I have a new account now but I'm never renewing my plus for the old account, I only ever use the new one.

So if I renew for the new account (the account that doesn't have the game) will I be able to play Black Ops 3 if the old account is still signed in?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to purchase the game for the new account as your current PS+ account does not have a record of the game being tied to it. You can try asking Sony support if they can close your old account and transfer the purchase records but I suspect you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with PSN, the games got via PSN Plus will be locked when the subscription ends.